# Why same paths are shown when running `which -a` command

Tags: command-line, which

When I run `which -a psql` the result shows three same paths.

```
/usr/local/bin/psql
/usr/local/bin/psql
/usr/local/bin/psql
```

I can run the command `psql` without a problem. I just want to know why this kind of behavior occurs. Have I misconfigured something?

Comment: Does `/usr/local/bin/` appear more than once in your `$PATH`?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/117549

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks! That was the cause of the behavior.